# HIVE: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hive, slf4j

I am trying to start hive, however I am recieving this error
Which file do I need to edit to solve this?

```
  a@a-VirtualBox:~/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/bin$ hive
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/a/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/libexec/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/a/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Comment: AFAIK that is not an error, just some mildly interesting comment from SLF4J. If your hive session is stalled and you never get the prompt, then it's probably an issue connecting to the Metastore service (and if the timeout is infinite then you will never get any useful error message...)